# No cached version of gradle - without disabling offline mode

Tags: android, gradle

I've seen there is lots of posts with this, and that the solution is to disable offline mode. My problem is that I need to find a solution without disabling it, since it shouldn't connect to the internet.

I can use other computer to pass files, so I've downloaded the latest version of Gradle (6.0.1), in `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle` I've put `Gradle home` referring to where I've decompressed the zip and in graddle-wrapper.properties set `distributionUrl=file:\\\\C:/Gradle/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip`

Let me know if I can provide any other information to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Usually, in such situations it helped me to uncheck offline mode, make a build and then check offline mode again. After that, everything worked fine.

Comment: Tried that with no luck